Remove default snippets but keep user-defined ones VSCode
I want to remove the default snippets for a specific language (latex), but I want to keep the ones I created
"[latex]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,
        "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "nickfode.latex-formatter",
        "editor.suggest.showSnippets": false
}

Using "editor.suggest.showSnippets": false will remove all snippets, but I want to keep the ones I created.
I'm working on latex using the LateX Workshop extension.
